# What is the meaning of "channels" in an audio recorder program?

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I compiled and ran this audio recorder program derived from JUCE: https://gitlab.com/DamienAuvray/simpleaudiorecorder

I can see that it has the options of selecting channels. I am a newbie in this area.
What do those channels represent? Do they represent different microphones? Selecting many channels means that we can use more than one microphone for recording?

Please explain.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about that particular software, but a channel is one of two sides of a stereo recording, and yes, a truly stereo microphone is in reality two separate microphones in one device.

Another option is to use two monoaural microphones connected to the same input device.

---

When a studio recording is being edited, a channel can represent this same; one of two microphones. There can be an even greater number of them, for example, a recording of an orchestra or they can be recordings from the same microphone made on different moments, for example, a solo artist that is recording his own chorus.

Comment: So this does mean having different channels can enable use to record from different microphones?

Comment: Channels are not necessarily part of a stereo pair. They can be the left and right sides of a stereo pair or they can be mono, independent recordings, or even part of a multichannel (5.1 or similar) configuration. Channels can definitely be used to record individual microphones. If you do that and you have the option, you should configure the channels to be mono, not stereo.